# How to get n-word combinations from a string in PHP

Tags: php

So what I am trying to do is to find out all the 2 word combinations(only present in string) from a string. For example,

```
$string = "This is a string";
```

Now, what I want to get as output is the array of all 2-word combos already present in the string, which will produce output like -

```
array("This is","is a","a string");
```

Note: I don't want extra combos like 'is this'(reverse), 'is string'(random).

Wonder if this can be acheived by a already present class? I've already tried using explode() function but it doesn't work.

Thanks :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. you can not just ask to provide a working code, show what you have tried

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service! We expect you to show us something that you tried already, and give us a proper problem description.

Comment: Pretty trivial to solve - explode at space to get an array of individual words, then do a `for` loop over that array from the first to second-to-last element, and in each iteration insert a new array consisting of the word at the current loop index position and the words at the next one, into your result array … done.

Comment: @O4FS well that implmention I tried, but I don't want extra combos like reverse ones, random ones, etc. as that'll create thounsads of extra words and increase the computation time for my algo. I want to get only the present 2 word combos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy! Explode the string, and loop:

```
$string = "This is a string";

$words = explode(' ', $string);
$pairs = [];

for ($x = 0; $x < (count($words) -1); $x++) {
    $pairs[$x] = $words[$x] .' ' . $words[$x + 1];
}

var_dump($pairs);
```

which gives:

```
array(3) { 
  [0]=> string(7) "This is" 
  [1]=> string(4) "is a" 
  [2]=> string(8) "a string" 
}
```

Which you can see in action here https://3v4l.org/8r2sn

Comment: Ooh hey, if I post a question from _my_ homework will you give me a good answer too? ;D

Comment: Hey @Sammitch how are you? :-D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = "Say hello wave goodbye";
$delim  = ' ';
$words  = explode($delim, $string);
$last   = null;
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(!is_null($last))
        $pairs[] = $last . $delim . $word;
    $last = $word;
}
var_export($pairs);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'Say hello',
    1 => 'hello wave',
    2 => 'wave goodbye',
  )
```